# How to shift elements in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a method that searches through the 'data' array to find the string 'elt'.  If it exists, it shifts all elements after 'elt' one position to the left (to cover the cell where 'elt' existed).

I am able to find all instances of "elt" and set them to null, but I am having problems shifting all elements past "elt" down one space in the array.  The code below is what I have so far.

```
public class Bag<T> implements Iterable<T> {

private final int MAXLEN = 3;
private int size;
private T[] data; // array

public T remove(T elt) {

        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if ("elt".equals(data[i]) ) {
                data[i] = null;

                for (i++; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = data[i-1];
                }
            }
        }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bag<String> sbag = new Bag<String>();

        sbag.add("Noriko");
        sbag.add("Buddy");
        sbag.add("Mary");
        sbag.add("Peter");
        sbag.add("elt");
        sbag.add("hello");

    Iterator<String> it = sbag.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String val = it.next();
            System.out.println(val);
        }

    sbag.remove("elt");

    Iterator<String> it2 = sbag.iterator();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            String val = it2.next();
            System.out.println(val);
        }
}
```

When I run that code, I get:

Noriko
Buddy
Mary
Peter
elt
hello
Noriko
Buddy
Mary
Peter
null

However, I am expecting

Noriko
Buddy
Mary
Peter
elt
hello
Noriko
Buddy
Mary
Peter
hello

Can anybody tell me how I can fix the code so that the rest of the items in the array are shifted down?  I think the problem is in my remove method.

Comment: Why does your expected output contains `etl` and `hello` instead of `null`?

Comment: It should print Noriko Buddy Mary Peter let hello with the first iterator.  Then, with the second iterator, I want it to print Noriko Buddy Mary Peter hello, because it removes elt from the array and shifts hello down in its place.  However, it is not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you're trying to achieve correctly, you're shifting the wrong way you want:

```
public T remove(T elt) {

    for (int i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
        if (elt.equals(data[i]) ) {
            data[i] = null;
            for (++i; i < data.length; ++i) {
                data[i-1] = data[i];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: It worked, thank you!  Would you mind explaining why this way worked but mine did not?

Comment: The issue with your code was the line   data[i] = data[i-1]; it was replacing the null with the next position value ,because you have already incremented the index to next position . So it will something like data[5]=data[4](null)